# How to save .ods spread sheet (OpenOffice.org) to .xlsx (MS Office Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Recently I switched from **MS Office** to **OpenOffice.org 3.4.1**.

Here are my questions:

1. I was not able to save .ods spread sheet to .xlsx 2007 Format.
   The option which I got when I use **Save As** was **Microsoft Excel 97/2000/XP (.xls) (*.xls)**
2. <s>I was not able to use in MS Office Excel 2007 **formula** in Open Office org.

   Example a Formula like

   `=IF(AND(A2<>"";B3<>"");"";IF(AND(B3="";B2<>"");"GO";IF(A3="";",";"")))`

   Here is the test file for **`Formula` [MS Excel 2007 and Office Org](http://www.ziddu.com/download/22229892/TestFormula.zip.html)**</s>

**Edit:**

Problem 2 is solved. The formula couldn't be copies at first. Also instead of `,` we have to use `;` in **OpenOffice.org**

But I am still couldn't figure out how to save as xlsx.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apache OpenOffice 3.4.1 (and earlier versions) does not store in OOXML formats (.docx, .xslx, .pptx).  I don't know if that will be remedied in the forthcoming Apache OpenOffice 4.0 or not.

An alternative that does have some conversion capability for OOXML in both directions is [LibreOffice](http://libreoffice.org).

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice Calc only opens, but doesn't save xlsx.

LibreOffice Calc also saves as xlsx, but the result will probably look weird with Excel.

If you want to get the best possible compatibility, I recommend using PlanMaker from SoftMaker. It has the best import and export filters for Microsoft Office formats and allows seamless interoperability.

PlanMaker is a part of SoftMaker Office which is commercial, but available for a fair price; if you don't want to spend any money, you can try out SoftMaker's Lite-Version FreeOffice which costs nothing, plus, btw., is much faster and smaller than OpenOffice and LibreOffice:

freeoffice.com

Comment: Just an FYI for any mac users that might stumble this way -- freeoffice only works on windows, linux, and android.